# pass parameter angularjs to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webclient

Hello i want pass  angularjs variable to javascript function

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2" ng-repeat="x in names | filter:FilterModeFirst">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-16 col--lg-12">
            <div class="callout">
                <small class="text-muted">{{x.name}}</small>
                <br>
                <small class="h6">{{x.Indx}}%</small>
                <img src="./img/Add.png" style="cursor:pointer" ID="imgAdd" onclick="AddServiceName(" {{x.name}} ")"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better to pass it into controller function (with `ng-click="AddServiceName(x.name)"`), which is initialised as `$scope.AddServiceName = function(name){...}`

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-click` and remove the curly brackets.

```
ng-click="AddServiceName(x.name)"
```

Answer (score 1):

angularjs provide `ng-click` for listening click event.

In your case, you can change the code to this:

```
ng-click="AddServiceName(x.name)"
```